# local directory while using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using PyInstaller to convert .py to .exe.

In the python code, the following command finds the local path of the .py file

```
path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

While running the .exe, the path is diverted to:
`...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI174042`

What is the proper way to find the local path of the .exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this to determine if the application is an exe or not

```py
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Answer (score 0):

When deploying an application, relying on the script location is not recommended. As you can notice, `pyinstaller` makes up a (virtual) environment on the fly to run your application.

What you can do, instead, is working with files or directories as **resources**, whose location is directly managed by `pyinstaller`, on the basis of your instruction in the `spec` file (or, equivalently, cli commands)

For example, from the [doc](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html):

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'src/README.txt:.' myscript.py
```

would make `README.txt` accessible from top level location of your application.

You can also use resources that belong to a submodule located in you application tree by accessing the homonymous folder. Again, from the documentation, given the module

```
helpmod
    __init__.py
    helpmod.py
    help_data.txt
```

And the `spec` file:

```
a = Analysis(...
         datas= [('helpmod/help_data.txt', 'helpmod' ) ],
         ...
     )
```

You can use `pkgutil` to safely access the resource

```
import pkgutil
help_bin = pkgutil.get_data( 'helpmod', 'help_data.txt' )
```

It much depends on what you need to access from your script location.

NOTE: if you instead are trying to access another script into the same folder, don't do that this way. Just use either relative import or make modules out of the script and import them.